# Is this the best option for IntStream nested loops and what is the error?

Tags: java, java-8

I want to create a triple nested iteration of numbers from 0 to 500, stepping by 10.

I tried the following and I get an error on the closing round brackets.
Can you please advise?

Thank you.

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 500).filter(a -> a % 10 == 0).forEach( a ->
                IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 500).filter(b -> b % 10 == 0).forEach( b ->
                        IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 500).filter(c -> c % 10 == 0).forEach( c->
                                System.out.println(a + ", " + b + ", " + c);
                        );
                );
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Of you get an error,  post the error message

Comment: remove all `;` except the last one.

Comment: or simply use nested for loops like that:
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i += 10) {
    }

Comment: My advice would be to design for readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of generating 501 elements in each stream and then filtering all the elements not divisible by 10, you can generate `IntStream`s that contain only multiples of 10:

```
IntStream.iterate(0, i->i+10).limit(51).forEach( a ->
            IntStream.iterate(0, i->i+10).limit(51).forEach( b ->
                    IntStream.iterate(0, i->i+10).limit(51).forEach( c->
                            System.out.println(a + ", " + b + ", " + c)
                    )
            )
);
```

Comment: Or `IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 50).map(i -> i*10)`…

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is:

```
    IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 50)
            .forEach(a -> IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 50)
                    .forEach(b -> IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 50)
                            .forEach(c -> System.out.format("%3d, %3d, %3d%n",
                                    a * 10, b * 10, c * 10))));
```

Excerpt from output:

```
  0,   0,   0
  0,   0,  10
  0,   0,  20
  0,   0,  30
  0,   0,  40

…
500, 500, 490
500, 500, 500
```

The `limit(51)` in [Eran’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52024461/5772882) looks a little bit funny.

**What went wrong in your code?** As Eran said in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52024422/is-this-the-best-option-for-intstream-nested-loops-and-what-is-the-error/52024913#comment90999093_52024422), you cannot have semicolon, `;`, after method invocations inside your stream (unless surrounded by curly braces). Just remove the first three semicolons, and your code works.